# Cairo Saved Paths with Transforms Render "Backwards"

Tags: cairo

The below code sample is in Lua, intended to be used with Conky.  My thought was to compute a complicated path, save it, then render it twice -- once as a filled region, then again as a stroked path, thus creating an outlined region.

The problem is that the saved path seems to render "backwards" compared to a straightforward rendering.

The first section creates a rotated L-shape in green, which appears as expected.

The second section attempts to create the same L-shape as a saved path, then render it in red.  The resulting path does not come out rotated, but since I didn't call `cairo_rotate()` before appending the path, I suppose this makes some sense.

The third section renders a set of progressively rotated L-shapes in cyan, which appears as expected.

The fourth section attempts to do the same thing as the third section, this time using saved paths, and rendering in yellow.  But the paths come out going in the wrong direction.

My *guess* is that the cairo transformation functions apply their transforms to the unstroked path components (if any) accumulated in the `cairo_t` context.  But I don't quite grasp why it would come out "forwards" one way and "backwards" the other way.

What am I misunderstanding about Cairo paths and transforms?

---

```
function tests (cr)
    local wiggle
    local mat_base = cairo_matrix_t:create ()
    tolua.takeownership (mat_base)

    cairo_set_line_width (cr, 4)
    cairo_identity_matrix (cr)

    ---
    -- Direct stroke of L-shaped figure.
    cairo_save (cr)

        cairo_translate (cr, 128, 128)
        cairo_new_path (cr)
        cairo_rotate (cr, math.pi / 6)
        cairo_move_to (cr, 150, 0)
        cairo_line_to (cr, 0, 0)
        cairo_line_to (cr, 0, 50)

        cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0, 1, 0)
        cairo_stroke (cr)

    cairo_restore (cr)
    ---
    -- Capture L-shaped figure as path, then render.
    cairo_save (cr)

        cairo_translate (cr, 384, 128)
        cairo_new_path (cr)
        cairo_rotate (cr, math.pi / 6)
        cairo_move_to (cr, 150, 0)
        cairo_line_to (cr, 0, 0)
        cairo_line_to (cr, 0, 50)
        wiggle = cairo_copy_path (cr)

    cairo_restore (cr)
    cairo_save (cr)

        cairo_translate (cr, 384, 128)
        cairo_new_path (cr)
        cairo_append_path (cr, wiggle)
        cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1, 0, 0)
        cairo_stroke (cr)

        cairo_path_destroy (wiggle)

    cairo_restore (cr)
    ---
    -- Direct stroke of a set of rotated L-shaped figures.
    cairo_save (cr)

        cairo_translate (cr, 640, 128)
        cairo_get_matrix (cr, mat_base)
        cairo_new_path (cr)
        for i = 0, 4 do
            cairo_set_matrix (cr, mat_base)
            cairo_rotate (cr, i * math.pi / 6)
            cairo_move_to (cr, 150, 0)
            cairo_line_to (cr, 0, 0)
            cairo_line_to (cr, 0, 50)
        end
        cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0, 1, 1)
        cairo_stroke (cr)

    cairo_restore (cr)
    ---
    -- Capture rotated L-shaped figures as path, then render.
    cairo_save (cr)

        cairo_translate (cr, 896, 128)
        cairo_get_matrix (cr, mat_base)
        cairo_new_path (cr)
        for i = 0, 4 do
            cairo_set_matrix (cr, mat_base)
            cairo_rotate (cr, i * math.pi / 6)
            cairo_move_to (cr, 150, 0)
            cairo_line_to (cr, 0, 0)
            cairo_line_to (cr, 0, 50)
        end
        wiggle = cairo_copy_path (cr)

    cairo_restore (cr)
    cairo_save (cr)

        cairo_new_path (cr)
        cairo_translate (cr, 896, 128)
        cairo_append_path (cr, wiggle)
        cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1, 1, 0)
        cairo_stroke (cr)

        cairo_path_destroy (wiggle)

    cairo_restore (cr)
    --
end
```

[image: Path rendering]

Answer (score 0):

When you call `cairo_copy_path`, the path is expressed in the current user space. So if you first draw some path and then afterwards call `cairo_rotate(), cairo_copy_path()`, then the resulting path will include the very same last rotation.

So in the red example, you copy the path before undoing the rotation and hence it appears like there is no rotation.

In the yellow example, you copy the path after all the rotation and thus the first rotations are in a different "direction" than in the blue one.

Try replacing `a = cairo_copy_path(cr)` with `cairo_save(cr) ; cairo_identity_matrix(cr) ; a = cairo_copy_path(cr) ; cairo_restore(cr)`. That way you get the path in surface coordinates which seems to be more like what you are expecting.